# Drupal 6 - theme the standard nodequeue admin view

Tags: nodes

I have a site where a client needs a 'visual' way of re-ordering their content. Is there a way to basically add more cck content to the nodequeue admin interface? so that it is not just showing a list of titles but instead maybe some cck content that the user can drag around?

I am thinking that I need to hack the module, which is fine, but wanted to know if there was some sort of recommended approach to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to prepare you listing according to your need. You can add as many CCK fields in column & expose filters too to use it further.

You can add your prepared views block at the dashboard which your admin can use.

Comment: You mean using this to build the interface... https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews - it's an ok solution as an admin screen. Going to try. Thanks!